# FreeBSD mount at reboot

Tags: freebsd, mount

In [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/), how do I automate the process of mounting of a directory into a [jail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail) at boot time?

Answer (score 2):

Reading through /etc/default/rc.conf there are some nice entries for setting up jails.  Most notable is:

```
#jail_example_exec_afterstart0="/bin/sh command"        # command to execute after the one for
                                                        # starting the jail. More than one can be
                                                        # specified using a trailing number
```

So you could use that to execute a script within the jail to mount a directory (as long as that directory is available from within the jail, such as NFS mounts etc).

Alternatively you would just ensure that the mounts are all done before the jail starts by using `nullfs` in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/path/to/source /path/to/jail/directory nullfs ro 0 0
```

Replace the `ro` with `rw` if you want to allow writing to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`nullfs` mounts](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/5/NULLFS/)? It's similar to bind-mounts on Linux. I.e. mount another location onto a folder.

Comment: I finally got it working by using the cron utility. Thanks for all of your suggestions. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The official way is to create a fstab from the host os's point of view and give it the jails name as an extension

eg

create /etc/fstab.jail1 for jail1
create /etc/fstab.jail2 for jail2